# How to get the UserName (not email) inside _LoginPartial.cshtml? - ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I tried to get it like this:

```
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

and like this:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

But i get the email instead of the `UserName` property.

Comment: sounds like their email address *is* their username

Comment: I have a UserName and a Email field in my DB and the values of them are different. UserName: test, Email:test@test.test Is there a way to get the UserName property via User.Identity?

Comment: then retrieve the username from your database

Comment: as I said, if you're calling `GetUserName()` and you're getting `test@test.com`, then `test@test.com` probably is the name that ASP.NET identity uses as their username. ASP.NET Identity doesn't know how to connect to your database and retrieve a different value automatically.

Comment: Is it not possible to use a `@model` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: sounds like another question. feel free to ask another question if you're having issues with something else.

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247416/is-it-possible-to-use-model-in-loginpartial-cshtml

Comment: @JoSmo I understand this is an old question and you find a similar question/answer. But I was wondering if you had a chance to look at my solution below which is much cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change a thing in _LoginPartial.cshtml file. Rather, in the AccountController change your Register Post from

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
```

to this:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.UserName, Email = model.Email };
```

Do remember though if you already ran the first code and registered a trial user into your DB then the UserName is set to the Email, so either delete that entry from your AspNetUser table or update the UserName and NormalizedUserName fields appropriately.

UPDATE: As stated here [gethub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7995) the Entity API checks login against NormalizedUserName. So when you offer a user upon RegisterViewModel to input a value that isn't an email, then you need to remove that [EmailAddress] validation in the LoginViewModel.