# Is it possible to use @model in _LoginPartial.cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

I need to get some data from my DB from `_LoginPartial.cshtml`. Is it possible to use `@model` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`? Or how is it done? Just by `@using WebApp.Services` and then directly retrieve the data from the service? Or it there a more elegant way doing this?

I tried to do it with `@model` but didn't work because the `@model` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml` got overridden by another `@model`. `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is "injected" into every page/view.

`Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml`

```
@model WebApp.ViewModels.LoginPartialViewModel
@Html.ActionLink("" + User.Identity.Name + " (" + Model.Email + ")", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

`ViewModels/ManageViewModels.cs`

```
public class LoginPartialViewModel
{
    public string Email = new UserService().ReadCurrent().Email;
}
```

And the `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` is used in `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml` like this:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

Could this be done with `@model` or would i have to do some nasty thing in `Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml` like this:

```
@using WebApp.Services
var userService = new UserService();
var email = userService.Read(User.Identity.GetUserId()).Email;
@Html.ActionLink("" + User.Identity.Name + " (" + email + ")", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: what do you mean "didn't work"? are you getting an error, or what's happening?

Comment: what do you mean got overridden by another `@model`? do you have two `@model` declarations in your `.cshtml` file?

Comment: The `_LoginPartial.cshtml` is "injected" into all pages, so yes... I guess that's what's happening.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question

Comment: Now include the code where you are using `_LoginPartial`

Comment: Will this be enough or do you need more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every page that uses `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` needs to do one of two things.

1. Pass a `LoginPartialViewModel` object into `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` as the model e.g. `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", loginModel)`
2. The model of the view that calls `_LoginPartial` needs to inherit from `LoginPartialViewModel`

Using `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` without the model override causes the partial view to inherit the view context of the parent view. So `_LoginPartial` wants to inherit whatever model type the calling view uses.

Comment: I like the first one `"Pass a LoginPartialViewModel object into @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial") as the model e.g. @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", loginModel)"`. So how how do i retrieve the `"loginModel"` in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`? I tried like this: `@{
                        var loginModel = new LoginPartialViewModel();
                    }
                    @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", loginModel)`

Comment: `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginPartialViewModel())` works otherwise you could create a property on the parent viewModel and set it at the controller level.

Comment: But then i would have to add it in all controllers. How do i access `new LoginPartialViewModel()` inside `_LoginPartial.cshtml`?

Comment: Just as you would with any view...`Model`

Comment: Yeah, I'm lost.  Mine tells me that LoginPartialViewModel could not be found on the line where I'm specifying @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginPartialViewModel()).  This is on the _Layout.cshtml page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass model object as a second parameter to `@Html.Partial` invocation.
But if this partial is used at every page, I suggest to move it to layout.