# How to get data into the _LoginPartial.cshtml page in .NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to be able to show custom data in the _LoginPartial.cshtml page, which shows as the header for all the pages on the site. But I have no idea how to get it there.

Everything I've looked at shows how to do this but they are all not at the root level of the site, which means a bunch of things that work in other places don't work here.

One thing that does work comes as part of the default code, and that's dependency injection for the SignInManager, but I don't know how that's done. When I do the DI the way I know how, I get errors about how it's not registered.

I can't pass data in to `_LoginPartial.cshtml` from the `_Layout.cshtml` page, because Visual Studio complains about the Model being dynamic (which is not the case).

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a  class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @User.Identity?.Name</a>
```

How do I get custom data into the `_LoginPartial.cshtml` page?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247416/is-it-possible-to-use-model-in-loginpartial-cshtml) might help.

Comment: @PeterSmith it doesn't, because the assumption is that there is a viewmodel for the page, but in the case _Layout.cshtml, there isn't a model.

Comment: what's the source of the custom data?  how are you trying to do your DI.  THis should work in program.js builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomData, CustomData>();   Then in the partial  @inject ICustomData CustomData.

Comment: @Stewart - you helped! I was injecting the concrete model and not the interface. I almost want to rewrite the question to that specific point. Or delete the question entirely.